# How to omit the hidden directories files using perl?

Tags: perl

I tried to fetch .config files from the particular location using perl.But i like to omit the same extension files from hidden directories.How can result to code as expected output:

code which i have tried:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name( '*.config' )
                            ->in( '/home/rsa/MODE/' );
for my $file (@files) {
    print "file: $file\n";
}
```

Output for above code:

```
file:/home/rsa/MODE/p_s/p1/b1/c3/r1/rev.config
file:/home/rsa/MODE/p_s/p1/b1/c3/r5/.bhat/rev.config
file:/home/rsa/MODE/p_s/p1/b1/c3/r5/.lrayan/rev.config
```

Expected output:

I should result the output without taking the hidden directories files extension.

```
file:/home/rsa/MODE/p_s/p1/b1/c3/r1/rev.config
```

Comment: Remove everything after the last `/` and check to see if the path-string still contains a dot (`.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has an example to skipping CSV directories. In this case, you need to do a bit more work, because `.*` matches `.` as well:

```
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new;

$rule->or( $rule->new
                ->directory
                ->name( '.*' )
                ->not_name( '.' )
                ->prune
                ->discard,
           $rule->new
                ->file
                ->name( '*.config' ));

my @files = $rule->in( $ENV{HOME} );
```

As [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) mentions in a comment, the `name->not_name` can be simplified by

```
->name( '.?*' )
```

or

```
->name( qr/^\../ )
```

i.e. dot followed by anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex pattern instead of a glob pattern in `name`, like so

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
        ->name(  qr/^[^.].*\.config$/ )
        ->in( '/home/rsa/MODE/' )
```